# React Hooks - setState takes two clicks before working

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-hooks, state

I have an array of tags that take an input and update when the user presses enter. For some reason, the user needs to press enter twice before anything happens.

```
const [ tags, setTags ] = useState([]);

const addTag = (inputEvent) => {
    if (inputEvent.key === 'Enter') {   
        setTags([ ...tags, inputEvent.target.value ]);
        inputEvent.target.value = '';
    }
};

return(

<input
  type="text"
  placeholder="Press enter"
  onKeyUp={(inputEvent) => addTag(inputEvent)}
/>
```

)

Comment: Can you show the element that calls this function? Also this ...`inputEvent.target.value = ''`... is not what you should be doing in React. That input's value should be tied to another value held in state, or in a form state.

Comment: Thanks James, I've included the input that calls it if that helps.

Comment: where do you need to show the tags?

Comment: need more info. please add your source code.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

1. Use the `ref` to access the current tag from your input field.
2. Use form so that it is easier to add the tags and listen to `Enter` submit.
3. On submit, update your tags, and reset your form using the ref.

```
import React from "react";

export default function App() {
  const [tags, setTags] = React.useState([]);
  const inputRef = React.useRef(null);
  const formRef = React.useRef(null);

  const addTag = (e) => {
    e.preventDefault();

    setTags([...tags, inputRef.current.value]);
    formRef.current.reset();
  };

  return (
    <div>
      <p>{tags.join(",")}</p>
      <form onSubmit={addTag} ref={formRef}>
        <input type="text" ref={inputRef} placeholder="Press enter" />
      </form>
    </div>
  );
}
```

Note :- It is advisable in React to use `ref` to access DOM elements and manipulating them.

You could check a working example here -> https://codesandbox.io/s/wispy-microservice-3j455?file=/src/App.js:0-469

Comment: Thanks Prateek! That works well and thanks for clarifying. I want to add in a way to remove an element when you click on it, is there an easy way to do that with hooks?

Comment: map your elements and slice it out of the array. that basic javascript. no need of hooks or whatsoeverm

Answer (score 1):

Need more context to be sure. But i would guess this is a classic stale state problem. Instead of `setTags([ ...tags, inputEvent.target.value ])`, try use the callback function signature:

```js
setTags(tags => [ ...tags, inputEvent.target.value ])
```

Comment: Thank you! this didn't change the problem it seems.. but have updated the question with the component calling addTag if that gives more context?